# Exporting the entire scope of a file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a game engine that I can use on the server side as well, and I planed to run it with Node.js.

The engine is in its entirety packed into one file, and at the end, I export it like this:

```
module.exports = Irenic; //Irenic is just the name of the engine. This is actually an object housing most of the classes and functions.
```

But, what if I made some functions outside of the `Irenic` object? For example, I redefined `setInterval` and `setTimeout` functions to track how many timeouts/intervals are active, and now I relized that I wont be able to use them outside of the file the engine is in.

How can I export everything in a file? (I already tried `module.exports = this;`, but it didn't work. Exported an empty object.)

**Edit 1**: I'd like to be able to simply `call()` the functions in the file I include the engine in, not do something like `exportedObj.call()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your engine + the functions into an object that you exports.

```
module.exports = {engine: Irenic, fun: function(){...} ... }
```

Comment: `var engine = require('./irenic').engine, fun = engine.fun, ...;` will allow you to use `engine`, `fun`, etc. on their own.